# Is there any way I can read environment name in .Net core 3.1 console app?

Tags: asp.net-core, worker-service

I have a .Net core 3.1 Worker service but whenever I am running it I am getting environment name as "Production" and it's taking appsettings.json as its file to read configs from. I want to deploy this service to Windows server where I have added ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT variable as "SIT" (Test environment) but still it uses appsettings.json and not appsettings.SIT.json.

I had same issue with my API project but there is used dotnet cli to publish and it made environment entry in web.config which worked for me. This is a console app.

Command which I used for api:

```
dotnet publish /p:Configuration=Release /p:EnvironmentName=SIT
```

Find below the code which i used to read environment name.

```
public static string CURRENT_DIR = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
          
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        BuildConfig(builder);
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

    }

static void BuildConfig(IConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.SetBasePath(CURRENT_DIR)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{ Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        }


 

   public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseWindowsService()
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        IConfiguration Configuration = hostContext.Configuration;

        

        var collection = new ServiceCollection();
        collection.AddOptions();
        collection.Configure<AppOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("AppOptions"));

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
        var env = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHostEnvironment>();
        ConfigureLogging(env);
```

Comment: Do you have a `public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)`? Post the contents if yes please. If not, how are you reading from the app settings? Where do you specify the name in the application? It won't read it automatically - share some code

Comment: I have used IHostEnvironment to get environment name.I have updated code used for the same